# webview turns black and application crashes

Tags: android, webview, crash, android-webview

My android application has multiple webviews. After few minutes of running the webview turns black and crashes the application.

This is the webview xml

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="63dp"
android:visibility="visible" />;
```

Here is the code to initialize webview in my Activity.

```
mywebPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mywebPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebPage.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mywebPage.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
mywebPage.setFocusable(true);
mywebPage.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mywebPage.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
        LogUtil.writeLog(this.getClass(), "WebView " + cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId());
            return true;
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your id in the `XML` with the id called in the `Activity` is not the same.
Try in the `activity` to define like this.
And as suggestion everytime when you define something you need to start with lowercase.
For example : `myWebPage`, `android:id="@+id/tvInfo"`.

```
myWebPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Info);
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to rename few ID's for security reasons. I missed to update them in the code.  Will update them to match. Thanks again.

Comment: I did a wrong copy + paste here. Actual code is perfect. We still have the issue though. Screen turns black at random and crashes.